# Errors using Wordpress functions from child theme functions.php

Tags: wordpress, parent-child

So i have a child theme in my Wordpress, works great. I have a functions.php in my child theme for some simple shortcodes. However, I am making a new shortcode, and I need to grab the featured image of a post based on post_id. So I have:

```
function kwn_in_th_news_teaser($atts){
         if($atts['count']){
             $count = $atts['count'];
         }else{
             $count = 4;
         }

        global $wpdb;
        $query = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC',ARRAY_A);
        foreach($query as $news) {
            if($i == $count) break;
            $thumbnail_id = get_the_post_thumbnail_id($news['postID']);
            $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id, 'liberty-blog-full');
            $return = '';
            $return .= '
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="profile-sidebar">
                            <div class="profile-userpic">
                                <img src="'.$thumbnail.'" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="profile-usertitle">
                                <div class="profile-usertitle-name">
                                    '.$news['news_headline'].'
                                </div>
                                <div class="profile-usertitle-job">
                                    '.$news['kid_name'].'
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p></p>
                            <div class="profile-userbuttons">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">View News</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View Story</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            ';
        }
        return $return; 
 }
 add_shortcode('news_teaser','kwn_in_th_news_teaser');
```

However, I get an error about an undefined function:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_the_post_thumbnail_id() in /blah/blah/blah/theme-child/functions.php on line 115
```

So how can I use basic wordpress functions from inside my child? I've been Googling this for over an hour to no avail. Any help is much appreciated.

~James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a typo in your question but the function in WordPress is `get_post_thumbnail_id()` not `get_the_post_thumbnail_id`

Comment: Wooooooow. /facepalm x 100   Thanks for pointing that out. I cannot believe that tripped me up for about an hour... I think I need to take a break now... thanks @caldwellysr

Comment: Happens to all of us. I'm sure you're familiar with the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org) but in case you aren't that is it. When I did WordPress I used that every single day. Anytime I got an error with a function I would look it up. That is how I found your issue, I looked up the function to see what parameters it took and realized it was typed out wrong.